# Sequelize: error of foreignKey constraint not reported when inserting new data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have table A one-to-many table B like below.

```
A.associate = function(models) {
    A.hasMany(models.B, {
        foreignKey: 'a_id',
        as: 'Bs'
    });
}
```

When I insert record B, I use a random a_id which does not exist in A. Therefore, I expect it to report error of foreign key constraint. But it doesn't report error, instead it adds B with a_id set to NULL.

Is there a setting to configure the model definition so that it can fail the operation and report error in such case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER MYSELF

Use "allowNull: false" in foreignKey.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2837